# Pythonでモジュールのimportエラーになる

Tags: python, ubuntu, opencv, numpy

Pythonでnumpyモジュールとcv2(opencv)のモジュールを使おうとしているのですがエラーになります。
ソースコードは以下の通りです。

---

**cap.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
import numpy as np
import cv2

print("test")
```

---

実行すると、以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/workspace/pythonCapture$ python cap.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cap.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name multiarray
```

cap.pyから

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
```

の部分の記述を消して実行すると、問題なく`test`とprintされます。

---

numpyを再インストールしてくださいとメッセージが出ていたので、$ `pip uninstall numpy`と`$ pip install numpy`をした後、`$ python cap.py`を再度実行してみましたが同様のエラーが出ました。

また、エラー文にgit clean -xdfを実行するようにあったので`$ git clean -xdf`をしてみましたが、cap.pyのファイルが消えただけで、エラーは直りませんでした。

```
$ git clean -xdf
Removing cap.py
```

---

$ pip showコマンドでnumpyの場所を一応確認してみました。

```
$ pip show numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.15.2
Summary: NumPy: array processing for numbers, strings, records, and objects.
Home-page: http://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: opencv-python
```

$ pip showコマンドでopencv-pythonの場所も確認してみました。

```
$ pip show opencv-python
Name: opencv-python
Version: 3.4.3.18
Summary: Wrapper package for OpenCV python bindings.
Home-page: https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: MIT
Location: /home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requires: numpy
Required-by:
```

numpyとopencv、共にsys.path.appendで指定した'/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages'のフォルダ内にあるようです。

---

どうしたらエラーを消せますでしょうか...?
環境は、Windows10 ProにVirtualBoxとVagrantでUbuntuの仮想環境を作って実行しています。

---

[追記]

```
sudo apt-get install libblas3 liblapack3 libc6
```

上記のコマンドを実行しても同様のエラーが出ました。
回答して頂いた下記のコマンドも実行してみました。
実行コマンドとエラー文を下記に記載します。

---

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-venv
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています                
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
E: パッケージ python3-venv が見つかりません
```

---

```
$ python3 -m venv env
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/workspace/pythonCapture$ souece env/bin/activate
souece: command not found
```

---

```
$ source env/bin/activate
-bash: env/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

---

```
$ pip install numpy opencv-python
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (1.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (3.4.3.18)
```

---

```
$ python cap.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name multiarray
```

Comment: `/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-34m.*.so` というファイル(shared library)はありますか？

Comment: pythonのglob.globで確認してみました。ファイルは存在しないようです。

Comment: python の `glob.glob()` では正規表現の形式が異なりますので(例えば、`.` は `.` にしかマッチしません)、`glob.glob("multiarray.cpython-34m.*.so")` などとしても当該のファイルにマッチしない可能性があります。念の為、Ubuntu のターミナル上（コマンドライン）で `cd /home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/` を実行して当該のディレクトリに移動した後、`ls -l multiarray*` を実行して確認してみて下さい。

Comment: pip uninstallをしてもキャッシュにビルドがFailしたnumpyが残っている可能性があるので、pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy をする方が確実かもしれません

Comment: $ cd /home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/
のコマンドでカレントディレクトリを実行した後$ ls -l multiarray*を実行してみたところ -rwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 2066272  9月 24 02:46 multiarray.cpython-34m.soと表示されました。

Comment: $ pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --user numpyを実行後も同様のエラーが出るようでした。--userオプションを付けないと私の環境では「Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy' Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.」というエラーが出てしまうようです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問にあるエラーは、numpyが使用する数値演算ライブラリーがインストールされていないため発生しているように思われます。`numpy`を`pip`でインストールしたのであれば、`libblas3`, `liblapack3`, `libc6`をインストールしてみてください。

```
sudo apt-get install libblas3 liblapack3 libc6
```

もし、それでも同じエラーが出るのであれば、仮想環境を作成してインストールしてみてください。

```
sudo apt-get install python3.4-venv
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install numpy opencv-python
```

Comment: 回答頂いた方法で追加のライブラリをインストール後に、cap.pyを実行しても最初の実行と同じエラーが出るようです。

Comment: 回答を修正しました。まだエラーは出ているでしょうか？

Comment: 修正＆回答して頂いた内容でコマンドを実行してみました。長くなったので説明文に追記いたしました。

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/760177/python3-venv-not-installed-ubuntu-14-04 に今回のエラーの原因がわかる回答があったので、回答を一部修正します。試してみてください。

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3-venv から sudo apt-get install python3.4-venv への修正です。

Comment: ご回答頂いた方法で実行することができるようになりました！