# numpyをimportするとエラーが出る

Tags: python, python3, numpy, blender

はじめまして。
こちらで質問させて頂いて良いものか判らないので相応しくなければ申し訳ありません。

3DモデリングツールのBlenderで「mmd tool」というアドオンを追加しようとすると、以下のエラーが表示されてしまいます。

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16<module> from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray' from 'numpy.core' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py)
```

UbuntuもBlenderも僅かな経験な上にPythonは全くの初心者なので、質問すべき場所がわからず、こちらにたどり着きました。
スタックオーバーフロー内で同様の質問があり回答も付いていたのですが、当方では解決できずにいます。

#### 実行環境

- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Blender 2.82.1
- Python 3.6.8
- numpy 1.16.5
- multiarrayは
  multiarray.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  multiarray_tests.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  のどちらが呼ばれているのか、もしくはどちらも呼ばれていないのか分かりません。

multiarray.soは存在しないので、シンボリックリンクでmultiarray.soに片方ずつ試したのですがやはり同じエラーで動かず、運用としてマズそうなので元に戻しています。

また、pipを使ったnumpyの再インストール、ライブラリの更新、`apt update`等は行いました。
Pythonは3.7をインストールしているのですが、3.6で説明されているサイトがほとんどなので3.6.8で運用しています。

簡単なことを見落としているのだろうと思いますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

### 追記

[こちらの質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48667/python%E3%81%A7%E3%83%A2%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AEimport%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B)に似ております。

ただあちらは呼び出し側のソースはご自分で書かれているので、全く同じとは言えないかもしれません。
またあちらは、Python3.4で解決したとの項目、`sudo apt-get install python3.4-venvはsudo apt-get install python3.6-venv`と置き換えて実行済みですが変わりありませんでした。

Python3.7については、質問のあと邪魔かと思いアンインストールしたので、現在は3.6.8です。
これはubuntu 18.04.3 LTSに付いていたものです。

### 追記２

Bash の上で Python インタプリタを起動し `import numpy` をしてもエラーは出ませんでした。`python` および `python3` どちらも試しました。それぞれのコマンドに対して `type` コマンドを実行するとこうなりました。

```sh
~$ type python
python は /usr/bin/python です
~$ type python3
python3 は /usr/bin/python3 です
```

エラーメッセージ全体はこちらです。コピペ出来ない上に出力される文字が小さくて…typoあったらすみません。

```
Traceback (most recent call last)

Import Error:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed. Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo. try 'git clean -xdf" (removes all
files not under version control). Otherwise reinstall numpy.

File"/usr/share/blender/2.82/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 351, in enable
mod = __import__(module_name)
File "home/名前/.config/blender/2.82/scropts/addons/mmd_tools/__init__.py", line 52, in <module> from . import propeties
File "/home/名前/.config/blender/2.82/scripts/addons/mmd_tools/propeties/__init__.py", line 16, in <module> from . import (
File "/home/名前/.config/blender/2.82/scripts/addons/mmd_tools/propeties/root.py", line 12, in <module> from mmd_tools.ore.sdefimport FnSDEF
File "home/名前/.config/blender/2.82/scropts/addons/mmd_tools/core/sdef.py", line 4, in <module> import numpy as np
File "usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module> from . import add_newdoc
File "usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module> from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8,in <module> from .type_check import *
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_checck.py", line 11, in <module> import numpy.core.numeric as_nx
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module> raise importError(msg)

Original error was: cannot import name 'multiarray' from 'numpy.core' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py)
```

Comment: エラーメッセージだけでは詳細が判りません。少なくとも、エラーがでた部分のコードは必須の情報です。

Comment: ソースコードについては配布されているadd onで他の方々は同じもので動いているようですし、エラーはPython3のパッケージ、
python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py内の
import multiarray
の一行で出ておりますので、ソースが原因でないと判断いたしました。

Comment: スタックトレースも出ていませんか？　Pythonのエラーメッセージは呼び出し元から最終的にエラーが出たところまで多段で出力されます。

Comment: Bashを立ち上げて`python`コマンドを実行し対話環境を立ち上げ、`import numpy` を実行すると同じエラーがでますか？　また、Bash上での`python`コマンドの実体を `type python` 等で調べて教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 見るのが遅れました。返答遅くなってすみません。
コマンド実行ではpython、python3ともにエラーは出ませんでした(@@)

~$ type python
python は /usr/bin/python です
~$ type python3
python3 は /usr/bin/python3 です

blender側の問題なのでしょうか？

Comment: スタックトレースはコメントでは見にくかったので質問に追記します。

Comment: OS,Blender共に古い版でエラーメッセージも微妙に違うようですが、こんな記事が参考になるかも。[Ubuntu Blender Installation, Python sys.path broken](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/102930)

Comment: 質問にあった「アドオンを追加しようとすると」を見落としてました。版数は合ってないですが、この辺の記事がmmd toolsのインストールを扱っているようです。参考になれば。[LinuxのBlenderでMMD toolsを使えるようにする](http://ultra-genma.hateblo.jp/entry/2018/06/25/002241), [Blender 2.8 beta EEVEE + mmd tools ①　基礎](http://9zhpw.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-15.html), [Blender 2.79（Linux版）でMMDモデルを読み込む方法](http://beginnersnote.main.jp/blog/?p=1387), [I'm trying to install this add-on: blender_mmd_tools](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23053)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
試してみます。

Comment: 上記サイトにアドオンの様々な導入方法があり、一通り試してみたのですが、やはり同じエラーで躓いてしまいます。色々調べて頂いてありがとうございました。当方、自分なりにも探しては見たのですが、blender側では無く、当方のシステムの問題に思えますので、一旦諦めます。感触としてはblenderからpython3を実行した時の環境なのかな？と思っています(コンソールからimport numbyをした場合はきちんと動作するため)。